WebSocket video streaming automatically adjusts quality based on the user's network status
I have three sources for my WebSocket video streaming, and I'm using JMuxer to display the video in the client's web browser. I need to implement automatic quality adjustment based on network status. For example, if the current stream is at 1080p but the client's network slows down, it should automatically switch to the 720p source.
The available streaming endpoints are:

/video?quality=360p
/video?quality=720p
/video?quality=1080p

I'm aware of the Network Information API, but I want a solution that directly adapts the video quality based on the client's ability to handle the current data stream.

Why use WebSocket for this?  There's no need.

@Brad it's low latency live stream.

Right, but why are you using WebSocket?  You could just use direct HTTP.  Or, if you really needed the lowest of latencies, you could use WebRTC and let it do all of its scaling logic on its own.  WebSocket doesn't add anything useful here, it's just adding an extra layer you don't need.

@Brad that's the problem I can't make any changes on the server side, in short I don't have access to it. The requirements should be done in client side. I've been proposing that before

If the buffer drops below a set threshold (e.g., 2 seconds), switch to a lower-quality WebSocket stream. If the buffer stabilizes above the threshold, try increasing the quality. Use the Network Information API as a secondary network speed indicator if available.
    let currentQuality = '/video?quality=1080p';
function switchQuality(newQuality) {
  if (currentQuality !== newQuality) {
    currentQuality = newQuality;
    websocket.close();
    initializeWebSocket(newQuality);
  }
}

function monitorBuffer() {
  setInterval(() => {
    const buffer = jmuxer.buffer.length;
    if (buffer < 2) {
      switchQuality('/video?quality=720p');
    } else if (buffer > 3 && currentQuality !== '/video?quality=1080p') {
      switchQuality('/video?quality=1080p');
    }
  }, 3000);
}

